# selenium installation hurdle "importfirefoxdriver"

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to download selenium web driver using eclipse and I am on the final step and successfully imported web driver, however, when I attempt to do the same for firefox I don't get the import option.  Any Suggestions? Is there anything wrong with the code below?

Code:

```
package webdriver_project;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class webdriver_module_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new firefoxDriver();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Firefox version 48 or later, you must first download Marionette Driver:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver
Choose a version suitable for your system (windows/linux, 32 or 64bit), download it and update the Path system variable to add the full directory path to the executable.
See an official information in the changelog: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/CHANGELOG

> Geckodriver is now the default mechanism for automating Firefox.
>   This is Mozilla's implementation of a driver for that browser,
>   and is required for automating Firefox versions 48 and above.

---

I am not sure how do you download selenium using eclipse. Did you download libraries (jars) from their page and place them manually as external jars in the Eclipse using *Java Build Path / Libraries* option?

Anyway, in my opinion the easiest way is to convert the project into Maven project:

- first install Maven plugin using Eclipse Marketplace option: http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/
- next right click on the project in Eclipse, and then choose *Configure/Convert to Maven project*. Next edit `pom.xml` file and add to it a dependency from Selenium webpage: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1</version>
  </dependency>
  ```

The whole content of `pom.xml` in my example project:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>WebKierowca</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebKierowca</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Finally create the below java class, change a path pointing to Marionette driver (geckodriver.exe), right click on this class and run it as Java application. If everything is ok, it should launch Firefox, go to google webpage, search a word "selenium" and display search results for 5 seconds:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String ... x){
        // Path to Marionette driver
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/serwery/geckodriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium");
        driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```